# Advanced macro with character recognition

Tags: macros, luatex

I would like to code an advanced macro that would look like

```
\begin{exercise}[....]
    bla bla bla
\end{exercise}
```

In the brackets `[....]`, I would put strings like :

- FFFHHC
- F
- HHF
- CCH
- ?
- etc.

The idea is to count to the number of `F`, `H` and `C` and take different actions depending on the result. In my mind, `FFF` will print three "lightning" symbols next to the exercise, `H` will print one star, `HH` two stars, `CC` two computer symbols, `?` will print one question mark, etc.

(`F` stand for "flash", `H` for "hard", `C` for "computer", `?` for "unknown", etc.)

What direction should I take? Do you have any hint (like somewhere where I could copy some code)? Any package that would help me?

I would prefer a `LaTeX` only solution but I'm also interested to know if `LuaLaTeX` can make this kind of things much easier.

Comment: There are some easy answers on the site using latex3 syntax to first split it into a list and then run a case construction on each char to determine what to do for each. So this is easily doable in latex, no need for lua

Comment: Do you have some links that I could use to learn how to do that?

Comment: your description is a bit contradictory, do you need to pre-parse the argument and count the number of H or do you just want t make H print a star C a computer symbol etc and so HH just prints two star naturally without counting? you can do either but obviously just printing teh string is easier

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I would like to parse the string before.

Comment: @Colas I may add that version but I'll post a simpler case (as I have just done it:-)

Comment: All your examples don't involve or require parsing the string before… or if they do, it's not clear what the requirement is. E.g. how should the output should differ for HHF versus FHH versus HFH etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{zzz}[1][]{%
\quote\strut\marginpar{\zzzz#1!}\ignorespaces}
{\endquote}

\def\zzzz#1{\csname zzz#1\endcsname\zzzz}

\def\zzzH{$\ast$}
\def\zzzF{$|$}
\def\zzzC{$\,\rule{4pt}{5pt}\,$}
\expandafter\def\csname zzz?\endcsname{?}
\expandafter\def\csname zzz!\endcsname#1{}

\begin{document}

\begin{zzz}
  one two three
\end{zzz}

\begin{zzz}[CCCH]
  one two three
\end{zzz}

\begin{zzz}[FF]
  one two three
\end{zzz}

\begin{zzz}[CF?]
  one two three
\end{zzz}


\end{document}
```

This directly prints the symbols but you could of course make the macros increment some counter instead and defer all printing until after the whole collection is known.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{zzz}[1][]{%
\quote\strut\marginpar{%
\Hc=0
\Fc=0
\Cc=0
\Qc=0
\zzzz#1!%
There are \the\Cc\ C and \the\Fc\ F}\ignorespaces}
{\endquote}

\def\zzzz#1{\csname zzz#1\endcsname\zzzz}

\newcount\Hc
\newcount\Fc
\newcount\Cc
\newcount\Qc

\def\zzzH{\advance\Hc1 }
\def\zzzF{\advance\Fc1 }
\def\zzzC{\advance\Cc1 }
\expandafter\def\csname zzz?\endcsname{\advance\Qc1 }
\expandafter\def\csname zzz!\endcsname#1{}

\begin{document}

\begin{zzz}
  one two three
\end{zzz}

\begin{zzz}[CCCH]
  one two three
\end{zzz}

\begin{zzz}[FF]
  one two three
\end{zzz}

\begin{zzz}[CF?]
  one two three
\end{zzz}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is an `expl3` implementation: with `\regex_count:nnN` we can set an integer variable to the number of occurrences of a letter and populate a token list variable with the number of required repetitions.

In this implementation, I set the symbols at the left of “Exercise“, in the margin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,marvosym,amsthm}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{innerexercise}
 {
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\l__colas_symbols_tl\enspace}Exercise
 }

\tl_new:N \l__colas_symbols_tl
\prop_new:N \g_colas_symbols_prop
\clist_new:N \g_colas_symbols_clist
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g_colas_symbols_prop % the equivalents
 {
  F=\Lightning,
  H=\textasteriskcentered,
  C=\Keyboard,
  ?=?,
 }
\clist_gset:Nn \g_colas_symbols_clist { F, H, C, ? } % the final order

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{o}
 {
  \IfValueT{#1} { \colas_symbols_add:n { #1 } }
  \begin{innerexercise}
 }
 {
  \end{innerexercise}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \colas_symbols_add:n
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__colas_symbols_tl
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_colas_symbols_clist
   {
    \regex_count:nnN { ##1 } { #1 } \l_tmpa_int
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__colas_symbols_tl
     {
      \prg_replicate:nn { \l_tmpa_int } { \prop_item:Nn \g_colas_symbols_prop { ##1 } }
     }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Simple one
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[FFFHHC]
Harder one
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[F]
Harder one
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[HHF]
Harder one
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[CHC]
Harder one
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[?]
Harder one
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried and copy/paste your code but it does not work. Here is the error:
`./bac_a_sable.tex:16: Undefined control sequence.
l.16 \prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn
                               \g_colas_symbols_prop % the equivalents`

Comment: @Colas You need to update `l3kernel` (and `l3packages`).

Comment: Which line of code should I add?

Comment: @Colas No line of code; update your TeX distribution

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with LuaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,marvosym,luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function convert(str)
   local symbols = {
      F = "\\Lightning",
      H = "\\textasteriskcentered",
      C = "\\Keyboard",
      ["?"] = "?",
   }
   local order = { "F", "H", "C", "?" }
   local count = {}
   for c in str:gmatch"." do
      count[c] = (count[c] or 0) + 1
   end
   for _,s in ipairs(order) do
      tex.sprint(string.rep(symbols[s],count[s] or 0))
   end
end
\end{luacode*}

\newtheoremstyle{exercise}%
  {}% space above
  {}% space below
  {}% body font
  {}% indent
  {\bfseries}% head font
  {.}% punctuation after head
  { }% space around head
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{\directlua{convert([[#3]])}\enspace}%
   \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}}% head spec

\theoremstyle{exercise}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Simple one
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[FFFHHC]
Harder one
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[F]
Harder one
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[HHF]
Harder one
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[CHC]
Harder one
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[?]
Harder one
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]